# How to sort a multi-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I was trying to sort an 2 dimensional array with both it's places and the first place having more precedence. For e.g. left array is unsorted and right is sorted answer.

```
[[1,2]                    [[0,9]
,[2,4]                    ,[1,1]
,[2,5]          ===>      ,[1,2]
,[1,1]                    ,[2,4]
,[0,9]]                   ,[2,5]]
```

It was easily done with `arr.sort((a,b) => a[0] !== b[0] ? a[0] - b[0] : a[1] - b[1])`. But then I thought how to sort a 3 dimensional array. <strike>Easy right? Just add another ternary operator.</strike>. (Actually my thought process was wrong). But how can I sort a n-dimensional array (when n is given). Is it possible to answer this question without loops and recursion (can use inbuilt and prototype functions like `forEach` `reduce` etc.).

**EDIT :-** 
3-dimensional array:- (It's already sorted)

```
[
[[1,2],[1,2]],
[[3,4],[7,8]],
[[5,6],[21,3]]
]
                            [arr,arr,arr]
                      [arr,arr]___|___[arr,arr] 
              [1,2]___|___[1,2]   |    [3,4]__|__[7,8]
                                  |                              
                          [5,6]___|___[21,3]
```

*(Family tree of the array)*

**EDIT:-** The answer may contain recursion or loop. I was just asking if it can be done without them.

**EDIT:-** The rules are that except the outermost array all other arrays can contain only two elements which can be a number or another array. The corresponding elements need not to be of the same type but numbers will have more value than arrays.If two corresponding numbers are equal than their right side numbers are compared. If they are equal too than there parent array is compared to it's right hand side array/number(Whatever it is).

Right hand side means comes later and is sibling.(Have a common parent array.(Not grandparent though))

Unsorted array example

```
[        
[[21,5],[16,18]],
[[12,45],[15,23]],
[[12,45],[15,22]]
]
To sorted =>
[        
[[12,45],[15,22]],
[[12,45],[15,23]],
[[21,5],[16,18]]
]
```

Comment: I don't think there are any in-built functions to sort n-dimensional arrays. What is the concern with recursion or loops?

Comment: @gurvinder372 The answer may contain recursion or loop. I was just asking if it can be done without them

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. what qualifies an array to be sorted before another?

Comment: If you all will wait 5 minutes I will write a deep explanation of the question

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated the question check it out

Comment: please add some unordered array and the the sorted. how does a parent array knows it place?

Comment: @NinaScholz Now it shall be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You could compute an array of the differences and find the first non-zero value:

```
arr.sort((arr1, arr2) => {
    let diff = arr1.map((el, index) => el - arr2[index]);
    return diff.find(el => el !== 0);
});
```

Comment: I think your function is utilizing 2 arrays. Please check the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the nested arrays by using an new property for each level with all sorted items of the next deeper level.

Then sort by this values `_` or sort just by the given elements, if the actual sorted array has no nested arrays.

```js
var array = [[[21, 5], [18, 16]], [[12, 45], [15, 23]], [[12, 45], [15, 22]]];

array.sort(function sort(a, b) {
    var i = 0;
    if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) {
        [a, b].forEach(function (c) {
            if (c._) {
                return;
            }
            c.sort(sort);
            c._ = c.reduce((r, d) => r.concat(d._ || d), []);
        });
        while (i < a._.length && i < b._.length && a._[i] === b._[i]) {
            i++;
        }
        return a._[i] - b._[i];
    }
    return a - b;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But n is variable so how long will you do it?

Comment: It is still 2 dimensional.. OP is asking *But how can I sort a n-dimensional array*.

Comment: @ChiefVOLDEMORT, please add an example of your 3d array.

Comment: ... you can use `n=2` for the current example.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through biggest length of the inner lists, assuming `0` if no value present:

```js
function sortMulti(a, b) {
  for (var index = 0; index < Math.max(a.length, b.length); index++) {
    var A = (a[index] === void 0) ? 0 : a[index];
    var B = (b[index] === void 0) ? 0 : b[index];
    var cmp = B - A;
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
//TEST
var lista = [
  [1, 20],
  [2, 4],
  [2, 5],
  [1, 1],
  [0, 9],
  [2, 2, 5],
  [1, 3]
];
var listb = [
  [0, 9],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 4],
  [2, 5]
];
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre"));
output.innerHTML = "Sorting multidimensionals:\nRAW:\nList a: [" + JSON.stringify(lista.join("],["), null, 1) + "]\nList b: [" + JSON.stringify(listb.join("],["), null, 1) + "]\nSORTED (biggest to smallest):\nList a: [" + JSON.stringify(lista.sort(sortMulti).join("],["), null, 1) + "]\nList b: [" + JSON.stringify(listb.sort(sortMulti).join("],["), null, 1) + "]";
```

**EDIT 1 - Version 2.0**

Here is a version that uphold the rules edited into the question:

```js
function sortMulti(a, b) {
    for (var outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < Math.max(a.length, b.length); outerIndex++) {
        var A = (a[outerIndex] === void 0 ? [0, 0] : a[outerIndex]);
        var B = (b[outerIndex] === void 0 ? [0, 0] : b[outerIndex]);
        for (var innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < Math.max(A.length, B.length); innerIndex++) {
            var cmp = (A[innerIndex] === void 0 ? 0 : A[innerIndex] - B[innerIndex] === void 0 ? 0 : B[innerIndex]);
            if (cmp !== 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//TEST
var list = [
    [[21, 5], [16, 18]],
    [[12, 45], [15, 23]],
    [[12, 45], [15, 22]]
];
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre"));
output.innerHTML = "RAW\n" + JSON.stringify(list.sort(sortMulti).map(function (a) { return JSON.stringify(a); }), null, 2) + "\nSORTED\n" + JSON.stringify(list.sort(sortMulti).map(function (a) { return JSON.stringify(a); }), null, 2) + "\n";
```

Comment: I updated the question now it might be clear too you what I am asking